# Mobile Device Manager 2008 SP1 With WSUS 3.1 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008, device-manager

Can I install MDM 2008 SP1 with WSUS 3.1 SP2?

It fails telling me I need WSUS 3.0 SP1 or higher.. but since I have SP2 shouldn't it work?

I'm installing on Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Same error here.

Works perfectly with WSUS 3 SP1, but not SP2.

Typical Microsoft...